# FusionTables Heatmap Layer Weighting

Tags: heatmap, google-fusion-tables, weighted

Is it possible to weight results within a `FusionTables` heatmap layer? For example, in my `FusionTable` dataset I have latitude, longitude, and counts. I'm not sure how to modify my layer to be weighted by my count field.

Here's a snippet of my layer:

```
layer1 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
    select: "'col1'",
    from: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    },
    heatmap: {
    enabled: true
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This currently is not possible with a FusionTablesHeatMap. You may use the data from the FusionTable and create a HeatMap-Layer(where weighted locations are supported), but of course it will depend on the amount of data if it's realizable.

Comment: Do you think the hearmap-layer would scale well?  I have data for about 36k zipcodes.

Comment: depends on the environment of the user, this would be about 2MB of data that has to be downloaded. A workaround would be to modify the table and  create copies of the weighted columns(e.g. 3 rows for a column with a weight of 3 and so on). This should result in a weighted HeatMap too(but I don't know if it's an option for you)

Comment: Probably not an option, that would be about 2 million rows.  What about a hearmap layer and JSON file?

Comment: You may test it, as I said it depends on the users environment. But you don't need a special JSON-file, you may request  fusionTable-data directly(JSONP is supported)